# How to get RSI data for 1 hour out of 5 minutes

Tags: pine-script-v4

I have a little problem, I am writing an indicator on Pine v4. I can't get the RSI data for 1 hour from a timeframe of 5 or 15 minutes. I look at the data for 15 minutes and compare it with an hourly chart. It shows anything, but not what I need. Perhaps someone has faced such a problem? I've been browsing the forums. I asked in the GPT chat. No one knows.

```
symbol_min = security(syminfo.ticker, "60", close)
rsi_min = rsi(symbol_min, 14)
plot(rsi_min, "rsi_min", color=#12e615)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMimR.jpg)

I wanted to get the RSI data for 1 hour.